# Integration (Fourier transform)

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

$\mathrm{Re}(i) = 0$, but the fourier transform of $f(x) = e^{-ix^2}$ is $g(\alpha) = \sqrt{\pi\over i}\times e^{i\alpha^2 \over 4}$, is it not?

Is there an easy to show that it is so, knowing the fourier transform of $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$? (It is $k(\alpha) = \sqrt\pi\times e^{-\alpha^2 \over 4}$.)

The non-unitary, angular frequency Fourier transform is taken into consideration.

Comment: Is there any textbook available online, for free, that would include this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure of a textbook, but I can tell you that a simple way to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: e^{-i x^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i}} = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}  $$

is to consider the integral

$$\oint_{C_R} dz \: e^{-z^2} $$

where $C_R$ consists of the interval $[0,R]$ along the $\Re{z}$ axis, a circular arc of radius $R$ centered at the origin, with endpoints at $(R,0)$ and $(R,R)/\sqrt{2}$, and the line segment from $(R,R)/\sqrt{2}$ to the origin.  Note that there are no poles inside of $C_R$, for any value of $R$.  Then take the limit as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and note that the integral along the circular arc vanishes. Apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem, and the desired result is shown.

Note that this analysis applies to the Fourier transform of such a function as well, as all the transform piece does is shift the center of the quadratic in the exponential.  The piece that is the transform is factored outside of the integral and doesn't change this analysis.

**EDIT**

To be explicit, we can write

$$\begin{align} \oint_{C_R} dz \: e^{-z^2} &= 0 \\ &= \int_0^R dx \: e^{-x^2} + i R \int_0^{\pi/4} d \phi e^{i \phi} e^{-R^2 \exp{(i 2 \phi)}} + e^{i \pi/4} \int_R^0 dt \: e^{-i t^2} \end{align}  $$

The 2nd integral vanishes as $R \rightarrow \infty$ because the exponential term in the exponent does not change sign within the integration region.  We may then conclude that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{i} \int_0^{\infty} dt e^{-i t^2}$$

or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \: e^{-i t^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{i}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i}} $$

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. I need to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i x^2}e^{-i\omega x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i x^2}\cos(\omega x)dx$ since $\sin(x)$ is uneven.

Now $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: e^{-i x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i x^2}(1-2ix) dx = \sqrt{\pi\over i} $ may be true, but so what?

Comment: Complete the square in the first integral.

Comment: $1-2ix-x^2+x^2 = (1-ix)^2$ and $-ix^2-iwx = -i(x+{w^2 \over 2}) + {iw^2 \over 4}$

Comment: I meant $-i (x^2 + \omega x ) = -i (x + \omega/2)^2 +  i \omega^2/4$

Comment: So $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i x^2}e^{-i\omega x} dx = e^{iw^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i (x+w/2)^2}d(x+w/2)$ but the integral you sugested is still not in the picture.

Comment: Now let $x \leftarrow x + \omega/2$.  This integral turns out to be the integral over the line segment from $(R,R)/\sqrt{2}$ to the origin, and when added to the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ over the real axis, equals zero by Cauchy's integral theorem, as I stated in the answer.  I'll clarify.

Comment: Thank you sir, I should have gotten it the first time.

Comment: One final question. We may conclude that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{i} \int_0^{\infty} dt e^{-i t^2}$$

but how does it follow that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \: e^{-i t^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{i}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: e^{-x^2} $$

Comment: $\sqrt{i} = e^{i \pi/4}$ (within a branch), so multiply both sides by $e^{-i \pi/4}$ (use same branch) which turns out to be $\sqrt{1/i}$.

Comment: I meant to ask how you change the lower bound in the definite integral from zero to negative infinity. How come $$\int_{-\infty}^0 dx \: e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{i} \int_{-\infty}^0 dt e^{-i t^2}$$

Comment: The integrands in both integrals are even, so I essentially multiplied both sides of the equation by 2.

Comment: This is about the integral over the arc in question. It is parametrized as $\gamma_R:z=Re^{i\phi}$ then $$\int_{\gamma_R} dze^{-z^2}= R \int_0^{\pi/4} d \phi e^{i \phi} e^{-R^2 \exp{(i 2 \phi)}} \not= i R \int_0^{\pi/4} d \phi e^{i \phi} e^{-R^2 \exp{(i 2 \phi)}}$$ Isn't that correct?

Comment: And one more thing. If you look at my first comment I say that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dxe^-x^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i x^2} (1-2 i x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^-x^2 dx$ when actually $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dxe{^-x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i x^2} (1-2 i x) dx \not= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$

Comment: @George: no; $dz = i R e^{i \phi}$.

Comment: But don't you have $\int_\gamma df(x) = \int_a^bdf(\gamma (t))$ since $$ \int_{\gamma} f^{'} (x)dx = \int_a^b f^{'} (\gamma (t))d\gamma (t)$$

Comment: I think I'll have to consider the integral 
$\oint_{C_R} e^{-{1 \over 2 }z^2}dz$
insted, since the last question still stands. It may prove easyer to transform to the desired $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ix^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4}}  $$
Yet how come $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\: e^{-i x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ix^2} dx$

Comment: I'm sorry, man, but when you say $\int dx \: f(x)$, do you in fact mean  $\int f(x) dx$?

Because $$df(x)=f'(x)dx$$

hence $$dx f(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)dx$$

and therefore $$\int dx \: f(x) = \int f(x)+xf'(x))dx$$ which is where the misunderstanding might stem from.

Comment: @rlgordonma. I don't see why the 2nd integral approaches 0 as R goes to infinity (b/c when $\phi=\pi/4$ the magnitude of the integrand is 1). How do we fix that?

Comment: @TCL: even if we were to lose that exponential decay at just the endpoint of the integration region, I think the integral would still vanish by Riemann-Lebesgue.

Answer (score 7):

The Fourier transform of $f(x) = \exp(-ix^2)$ doesn't exist in the usual sense. Note that $f \notin L^1$.

However, the function $f$ is bounded and continuous and, as such, can be identified with a tempered distribution, so $\hat f$ exists, also as a tempered distribution. Working out the details, you do in fact end up with

$$\hat f(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-i) e^{i\omega^2/4}$$

which is the same as what you have written, with a suitable interpretation of $\sqrt{i}$. The approach outlined by rlgordonma is probably the easiest way to get to the result.

Comment: You are right that $f\neq L^1$, but still the Fourier transform exists as an improper integral (no distribution theory needed).

Comment: @Fabian Yes, but it feels wrong to talk about Fourier transforms in terms of Riemann integrals. The required integrals don't exist as Lebesgue integrals. (The approach suggested by rlgordonma that I endorsed is distribution theory free.)

Comment: @mrf Note that there _is_ [a notion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Improper_integral) of improper Lebesgue integral of a function in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ (in $\mathbf R^n$, [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214709/) in an arbitrary measure space), and it’s required if you want to integrate things like $\sin x/x$. Amusingly, I first encountered it while reading about improper integrals of _distributions_ ([R. Wawak, _Studia Math._ **86** (1987), 205–220](https://eudml.org/doc/218762)).