# Proof of $\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{it}\,dt=\Gamma(a)e^{ia\pi/2}$?

Tags: analysis, integration, special-functions

Can anyone show a proof of $$\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{it}\,dt=\Gamma(a)e^{ia\pi/2}$$
where $0<a<1$, and $$\Gamma(a)=\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$ Thank you.

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285348/integration-fourier-transform

Comment: and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an integral in the complex plane along the contour which goes from the origin out along the real axis to $+R$, then moves in a circular arc up to the point $+iR$, and then returns to the origin along the imaginary axis.

Comment: Or go up to $\frac {(R,R)} {\sqrt 2}$ and back to the origin. Shouldn't that work @Jonathan?

Comment: That contour would not work with the integrand I have in mind (which is the natural one for this problem), but perhaps with a different integrand.